# Split String using multiple delimiters in one step

Tags: java, regex, string

My question is on splitting a string initially based on one criteria and then splitting the remaining part of the string with another criteria. I want to split the email address below into 3 parts in Java:

```
String email = "blah.blah_blah@mail.com";
// After splitting i want 3 separate strings (can be array or accessed via an Iterable)
string1.equals("blah.blah_blah");
string2.equals("mail");
string3.equals("com");
```

I know I can first split it into two based on `@` and then later split the second string based on `.`, but is there anyway of doing this in one step? I don't mind either the `String#split` method or regex method using `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: ^(?<local>[^@]+)@(?<domain>[^\.]+)\.(?<tld>.+)$

Comment: @noob ya like i mentioned i have done it by first splitting the local part and then again splitting the mail.com by the period(.)

Thats two separate steps. Im trying to see if it can be done in one step.

Comment: If you have something then include that in your code.

Comment: What should be result for `foo@bar.edu.en`?

Comment: @rapidclock We still don't know what is your preferred result for `foo@bar.edu.en`. Accepted answer includes solution for both cases (1) split only on last dot after @, (2) split on all dots after @. So which case is preferred?

Comment: @Pshemo to be honest, i didn't consider that case. But now i guess since i have both solutions i guess the second one is the one i want.

Comment: @rapidclock You should probably put that information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex in your split:

### `@|[.](?!.*[@.])`

It will split at an `@` ***or*** at the very last `.` after the `@` (the one before "com").  [Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/fS4xW4/4)

Use it like this:

```
String[] emailParts = email.split("@|[.](?!.*[@.])");
```

Then `emailParts` will be an array of the 3 strings that you want, in order.

---

**As a bonus**, if you want it to split at *every* dot after the `@` (including the ones between subdomains), then remove the `.` from the character class at the end of the regex. It will become `@|[.](?!.*@)`

Comment: I made a quick Java program in order to test it out, and it's working perfectly. You can also see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/fS4xW4/1).

Comment: I updated my answer to make it even easier to switch between splitting at sub-domains or not.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to split on
- `@`
or
- any dot that is after `@` (in other words has `@` somewhere before it).

If that is the case you can use `email.split("@|(?<=@.{0,1000})[.]");` which will return `String[]` array containing separated tokens.

I used `.{0,1000}` instead of `.*` because [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) needs to have obvious max length in Java which excludes `*` quantifier. But assuming that `@` and `.` will not be separated by more than 1000 characters we can use `{0,1000}` instead.

Comment: What if there are subdomains? They only want to split at the last dot in the email. In which case they should use my answer.

Comment: @4castle "*They only want to split at the last dot in the email*" why do you think so? I am not saying you are not right but I can't see such requirement in OP question/comments.

Comment: Considering they want exactly 3 strings to be the result, I'm assuming they are referring to the dot that separates the (sub)domain from the top-level domain (com/net/org). Otherwise if they wanted to also split at sub-domains, then they wouldn't have specified 3 parts.

Comment: @4castle That is fair assumption but still it is only assumption. It could also be that we are getting 3 strings because based on that example and OP requirements correct answer must contain these 3 parts. "*later split the second string based on (.)*" is not very precise here, so we need to wait for OP to clarify that. I left comment under question asking how something like `foo@bar.edu.en` should be split so we will need to wait for response.

Comment: I added a part to my question that also allows for separating at subdomains.

Comment: It works fine in Java. [Like I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120163/split-string-using-multiple-delimiters-in-one-step/36120312#comment59881846_36120312) avoid regex101 to test Java regex.

Comment: @Pshemo Maybe we can add a negative look-ahead for dot to your regex to capture as `bla1.bla2.bla3` `com`

Comment: @Saibot we can, but I want my split to work in a way that will split `foo@bar.baz.com` into `foo` `bar` `baz` `com` instead of `foo` `bar.baz` `com`. If that is not what OP wants then I can simply delete this answer since there are other answers which do what OP probably wants.

Comment: This answer can be improved by using a negative look-ahead instead of a positive look-behind (what I have in my answer). That way you don't have to worry about setting a limit to the look-behind.

Comment: @4castle True, but to avoid posting duplicate answers I will leave it as is. I suspect that 1000 limit is OK in this case.

Comment: @Pshemo We got a troll downvoter, but really, just don't care.

Comment: @Pshemo Upvoting your answer. And btw, can you please show how to add a negative look-ahead to achieve 3 part split? Because I tried to modify your regex for this but I couldn't.

Comment: @Pshemo I downvoted because the answer uses a hack instead of doing what is best for the question (using a negative look-ahead).

Comment: @Saibot I wouldn't care if my answer would be *wrong*, but from what I see it simply uses different approach and is based on little different assumption about OP requirements. 4castle hacky or not it *works* for reasonable input so I can't agree with your vote. But lets agree to disagree here.

Comment: I'm simply trying to distinguish for the OP what they should use IMO. Your answer doesn't have any more capabilities than mine does (see my bonus).

Comment: @4castle I don't think we should downvote the answers which are not the best. Different approaches are always valuable to learn something. But it seems you prefer to downvote every other answer than the best answer, OK, your choice.

Comment: My reasons for downvoting still stand. I agree that it is inappropriate to downvote just because it isn't the best.

Comment: @4castle "*Your answer doesn't have any more capabilities than mine does*" true, but it doesn't mean it is *wrong*. Just because someone thinks that one answer is better than other, doesn't mean he should downvote that other answer. Downvotes are meant to be used on answers which are not correct/helpful. But again it is your choice how you distribute your votes, if you believe that this answer deserves it then I don't mind. Just wanted to know the reason (I don't need to agree with it).

Comment: @Pshemo Found it: `@|(?<=@.{0,1000})[.](?!.*[.])`

Comment: @Saibot Oh, I didn't see you ware looking for something :). Congrats on solution. Requiring from `dot` to not have more `dot`s means that `dot` on which we can split must be the last one (this idea is also used in 4castle's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
([^@]*)@([^@]*)\.([^@\.]*)
```

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wD7kJ2/2)

Here is the example Java code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JavaRegex
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        String line = "blah.blah_blah@mail.mail2.com";
        String pattern = "([^@]*)@([^@]*)\\.([^@\\.]*)";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3));
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for Pshemo for pointing out that look-aheads were unnecessary.

Comment: That's great but this requires inspecting the capture groups, which would mean it isn't "in one step".

Comment: Actually, this is one step. Just apply the regex, and you get the result.

Comment: Okay, so how would you get the result using this regex?

Comment: Different question: what is the purpose of `(?=@)` and `(?=\.)` here? Don't you think `(?=@)@` is overcomplicated? Is there any case where test `(?=@)` would fail here? Same about `(?=\.)\.`.

Comment: I am going to update the example answering your questions. Hold on.

Comment: Also, you can change the first capture group to `[^@]*` instead of `.*` in order to greatly speed up your regex. That way it doesn't have to backtrack when it encounters the `@`.

Comment: @4castle Yeah that's true, I didn't want to complicate the regex too much.

Comment: "*First positive look-ahead ?=@ makes sure, you only capture the part before the @ sign*" same could be achieved with `(.*)@` or even better with `([^@]*)@` which will prevent backtracking. Test your code with `String pattern = "(.*)@(.+)\\.(.*)";` and you will see no difference.

Comment: Just to be precise, I am not saying that `(?=@)` is *wrong*. I am saying it is *redundant*.

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah, after your comment, I felt like that too, I'm checking it now, if it's better or not.

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah, you are right, I'm already matching @ sign after lookahead, if I'm gonna match it, there is no need to lookahead. I'm going to update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Pshemo OK, but it was not a duplicate answer, your approach was different and I liked it. I believe you should post the answer back.

Comment: I'm downvoting because it doesn't solve the problem "in one step". It would be better to do what the question described instead of this.

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = "blah.blah_blah@mail.com";
String[] tempMailSplitted;
String[] tempHostSplitted; 
String delimiter = "@";

tempMailSplitted = str.split(delimiter);

System.out.println(temp[1]); //mail.com


String hostMailDelimiter = "."

tempHostSplitted = temp[1].split(hostMailDelimiter);
```

You can also do it in a regex if you want that ask me. :)

Comment: You forgot about "...in one step" part.